# Как при получение значение input провести с ними вычесление?

Tags: javascript, input, javascript-events

Есть вот такое задание: Дан input .i-141 и .i-142, type=number. Дан select .s-143, который содержит две операции - +, -, *, / . Дана кнопка b-14, при нажатии на которую срабатывает функция f14. Функция выводит в .out-14 результат операций выбранной в 3-м select к числам введенным в первом и втором input. Например выбрано 1 13 +, нужно вывести результат операции 1+13 т.е. 14. Заранее благодарю за помощь. Вот такой кусочек сделал

```js
let inputI141 = document.querySelector('.i-141');
let inputI142 = document.querySelector('.i-142');
let select143 = document.querySelector('.s-143');
let btnB14 = document.querySelector('.b-14');
let out14 = document.querySelector('.out-14');

btnB14.addEventListener('click', () => {
    out14.innerHTML = +inputI141.value + select143.value + +inputI142.value;
});
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Task 14.</h4>
   <p>Дан input .i-141 и .i-142, type=number. Дан select .s-143,         который содержит две операции - +, -, *, / . Дана кнопка b-         14, при нажатии на которую срабатывает функция f14. Функция         выводит в .out-14 результат операций выбранной в 3-м select к       числам введенным в первом и втором input. Например выбрано 1       13 +, нужно вывести результат операции 1+13 т.е. 14.
   </p>
   <div>
      <input type="number" class="i-141" value="8">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="number" class="i-142" value="7">
   </div>
   <div>
      <select class="s-143">
          <option value="+">+</option>
          <option value="-">-</option>
          <option value="*">*</option>
          <option value="/">/</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="button-primary b-14">Task-14</button>
    <div class="out-14"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

День добрый, @whoismatvei.
Сам больше времени провожу с Python.
В поле инпут оставляю атрибут `name`, помимо `value` Тем самым значение `value` присваиваю к переменной `name`.
Далее переменную обворачиваю в тот тип данных который мне необходим `int(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Значения, получаемые с инпутов/селектов, сточного типа. Поэтому все дальнейшие операции бессмысленны без приведения к числовому типу. Знак с селекта вы не сможете просто вставить в исполняемый код, поэтому в зависимости от значения селекта нужно вызывать соответствующую операцию.

Ниже пример:

```js
let inputI141 = document.querySelector('.i-141');
let inputI142 = document.querySelector('.i-142');
let select143 = document.querySelector('.s-143');
let btnB14 = document.querySelector('.b-14');
let out14 = document.querySelector('.out-14');

btnB14.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let first = parseInt(inputI141.value);
    let second = parseInt(inputI142.value);
    let sign = select143.value;
    let res;
    switch (sign) {
      case '+':
        res = first + second;
        break;
      case '-': 
        res = first - second;
        break;
      case '*': 
        res = first * second;
        break;
      case '/': 
        res = first / second;
        break;
    }
    out14.innerHTML = res;
});
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Task 14.</h4>
   <p>Дан input .i-141 и .i-142, type=number. Дан select .s-143,         который содержит две операции - +, -, *, / . Дана кнопка b-         14, при нажатии на которую срабатывает функция f14. Функция         выводит в .out-14 результат операций выбранной в 3-м select к       числам введенным в первом и втором input. Например выбрано 1       13 +, нужно вывести результат операции 1+13 т.е. 14.
   </p>
   <div>
      <input type="number" class="i-141" value="8">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="number" class="i-142" value="7">
   </div>
   <div>
      <select class="s-143">
          <option value="+">+</option>
          <option value="-">-</option>
          <option value="*">*</option>
          <option value="/">/</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="button-primary b-14">Task-14</button>
    <div class="out-14"></div>
</section>
```